# How many species of animals did God create in total?

Tags: animals, science, creation

In Rabbis' views, how many species of animals did God create in total?

How did those views evolve with time and scientific understanding?

Comment: How do you define species

Comment: I doubt this is addressed anywhere

Comment: I think most mefarshim speak of "creatures" or "several species" (see for example Haamek Davar; Bereishis 1:21:1) and not specifically "10 or 100 etc...".

Comment: @robev Question seems perfectly clear, and is exactly the sort of thing I would be unsurprised to appear in a midrash.